# How to Append to the_excerpt() Function

Tags: php, functions

I have the following snippet of code:

```
<?php>$more = '.....';?> 
<p class="extra"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
```

What I am trying to do is append the value of $more to the_excerpt() function but unsure how to do.

I have tried:

```
<p class="extra"><?php the_excerpt() . $more; ?></p>
```

but no go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
sp.

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...'; // <-- your end string
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more

---

The above solution is the preferred, but to make this work:

```
<p class="extra"><?php the_excerpt() . $more; ?></p>
```

Change it to:

```
<p class="extra"><?php the_excerpt(); echo $more; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just echo out the `$more` after the excerpt:

```
<p class="extra"><?php the_excerpt(); echo $more; ?></p>
```

or a better solution would bet the use a filter and leave the template as is, for example your template uses just `the_excerpt()`

```
<p class="extra"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>


<?php
//and this goes in your theme's functions.php file
add_filter('the_excerpt','my_excerpt_more');
function my_excerpt_more($excerpt){
   return $excerpt. '.....';
}
```