# Posts showing [...] in it

Tags: posts

I have seen a bug on [my website](http://www.apptec.net/). It appeared just few days back and was not present before so I am suspecting a plugin updgrade to be the reason for it. The problem is that when I open a post for reading, it shows me `[...]` after about 300 characters(just guessing the characters). This is the same truncation that is done on the page which shows the list of all articles on my website. How can I remove it? Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Its not a bug! Its called an excerpt, and the [...] is called an ellipsis, means there is more content than what is seen over here! Use a filter if you're familiar with, or switch the theme!

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47808/how-to-append-to-the-excerpt-function/47811

Comment: it seems that the single.php template is showing the excerpt **and** the content. have you edited single.php in any way? what happens if you deactivate all plugins?

Comment: @Michael: I tried to deactivate all plugins and then see what happens but ellipsis was still there. I created a filter for it and it works fine now.

Comment: it has not changed the fact that the first few lines in a single post are still double - just without the dots ... next step would be to look into single.php to see if anything has changed there.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for pointing it out. I just missed to see that. I will look into single.php

Comment: If the below did answer your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you place the following in your functions.php it will remove it. Hope it helps!

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'my_remove_excerpt_more' );

function my_remove_excerpt_more() {
    return '';
}
```